# QQuickPaintedItem is not aligned properly

Tags: qt, qml

I have created a custom QQuickPaintedItem in C++, but when using it the QML side inside a ColumnLayout it ignores Q.AlignHCenter attribute. The only way to align it is to put my custom Item into an `Item` element. For example:

This DOESN'T work, the item is placed more on the right than true centered:

```
BalanceItem {
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    id: acct_balance_item
}
```

This DOES work, the item is trully centered:

```
Item {
    Layout.preferredWidth: acct_balance_item.width
    Layout.preferredHeight: acct_balance_item.height
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    BalanceItem {
        id: acct_balance_item
    }
}
```

My paint method goes like this:

```
void BalanceItem::paint(QPainter* painter) {
    int w;
    int accum_w=0;
    QColor hi_color;

    hi_color.setRgb((unsigned int) 0x00ffffff);
    QColor dot_color((QRgb) 0x00FFFFFF);
    QColor lo_color((QRgb) 0x00888888);

    QPen pen(hi_color, 2);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    QFont font=painter->font();
    font.setPointSize ( 12 );
    font.setWeight(QFont::Bold);
    QFontMetrics fm(font);
    w=fm.width(this->hi_fmt);
    painter->setFont(font);
    painter->drawText(QPoint(0,20),this->hi_fmt);
    accum_w+=w;

    w=fm.width(".");
    pen.setColor(dot_color);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->drawText(QPoint(accum_w,20),".");
    accum_w+=w;


    font.setWeight(QFont::Normal);
    fm=QFontMetrics(font);
    w=fm.width(this->lo_fmt);
    painter->setFont(font);
    pen.setColor(lo_color);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->drawText(QPoint(accum_w,20),this->lo_fmt);
    accum_w+=w;

    QString symstr(" "+this->symbol);
    w=fm.width(symstr);
    painter->drawText(QPoint(accum_w,20),symstr);
    accum_w+=w;

    this->fld_width=accum_w;
    this->setWidth(this->fld_width);
}
```

What I suspect is that it uses initial width of the item set by the `Constructor` , but this width is only initial setting, the real width is recalculated during paint() method, at the end.

So, how do I make my custom QQuickPaintedItem properly aligned in a ColumnLayout?

Comment: provide a [mcve], please

Comment: @eyllanesc, yes, that's right, it uses previous width. Should I emit new signal saying that the width has changed or  will the method `this->setWidth(new_width)` do this for me?

Comment: is that you are changing the width when it is already drawn, the calculation must be before drawing it.

Comment: I moved it out of `paint()` but when I set the width with `this->setWidth(new_width)` I am still reading the old width within `paint()` , even when `paint()` is being called after `setWidth()`

Comment: but it works if I put the QQuickPaintedItem in a dummy container. Maybe the Layout has read the old width and keep using it even after the real width has already changed

Comment: You should never ever modify anything about an item when you paint it. The `paint` method should paint and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code doesn't work because the `ColumnLayout` modifies the width and height of your `BalanceItem`. That's what layouts do in Qt Quick, they manage the sizing and positioning of their children. In order to do that, they need to know what size their children are.

And they can't do that with `width` and `height`, cause they'll modify it later on.
In your second example, had you done `width: acct_balance_item.width`, it would have failed too. The width and height of the `Item` would have ultimately been 0.

To tell a layout what size an item wants to be, they are 2 solutions. The one you used with the `Layout` attached properties `preferred|minimum|maximum/Width|Height` or the one with the `implicitWidth`/`implicitHeight` properties of `Item`/`QQuickItem`.

The implicit sizes is the size an item takes when no explicit sizes is set to it (with `width` and `height`). Some items have implicit sizes set to 0 (like a plain `Item` or `Rectangle`), but some may define their implicit size to inform a parent/user of the size it makes sense to default to. For example a `Text` define its implicit size so that it can fit all its text. But you can force on it a specific width, and the `Text` may then wrap or elide its `text` if the explicit `width` is smaller than its `implicitWidth`.

So your problem was that your `BalanceItem` has a width and height of 0 in your `ColumnLayout`, but you did not notice that because clippling is not enabled by default, and you painted outside your item's dimensions in your `paint` method.

When defining an item component, you should not set its `width` or `height` properties. If it makes sense for your item, you can define an `implicitWidth` or `implicitHeight`.

You could also handle explicit sizes by only painting in the item's area, if you can somehow squish/expand your component. But you don't have to if you can't/don't want to (`Text` doesn't do it if you don't enable eliding or wrapping).

To mitigate your future item geometry problems you could try debugging it by putting a child `Rectangle` with some color and `anchors.fill: parent`, maybe some opacity, to visualize the size taken by your item. Or use the excellent Qt debugging software [GammaRay](https://www.kdab.com/development-resources/qt-tools/gammaray/).